# Having an issue rendering an SVG icon, using Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, html, svg, webpack

**What I'm trying to do:**
 Render an svg icon.

**My results:** Although svg and img property append to DOM, HTML does not render icon and I get no webpack or browser error.

**My component file structure/ approach** 
[I import SVG into sidebar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF2XS.png)

*sidebar.js*

```
import './sidebar.scss';
import photo from './usrPic.jpg';
import '../base/SVG/twitter.svg';
import  '../base/sprite.svg';



export default class Sidebar {


    render() {

        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.alt = 'image';
        img.width = 200;
        img.src = photo;
        img.classList = 'sidebar__user-photo';

        // const svg = document.createElement('svg');


        const use = document.createElement('use');
        use.setAttribute('href', `../base/SVG/twitter.svg#icon-twitter.svg`);

        const html = `<div class="sidebar-box">
                        <div class="sidebar-header">
                            <span class="sidebar-title__main">Something</span>
                            <span class="sidebar-title__sub">Sub</span>
                            <div class="Icon-box">
                                <svg class="twitter__icon">


                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
        const contentBox = document.querySelector('.content');
        contentBox.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

        const sidebarHeader = document.querySelector('.sidebar-header');
        sidebarHeader.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", img);

        const twitterIcon = document.querySelector('.twitter__icon');
        twitterIcon.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", use);
    }
}
```

*webpack.dev.config*

```
...
    {
       test: /\.svg$/,
       use: 'svg-sprite-loader'

     },
     {
       test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
       use:  'file-loader',
     },
```

*html*

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhfGT.png)

**What I have tried thus far:**

1. swapping sprite.svg with direct icon.svg in `<use href="..." />`
2. I swapped `<use href="..." />` . with `<use xlink:href="..." />`
3. I swapped the  element with "img" property.
4. Applied a 40px to width & height on svg element

   Given all this, I do not get an error yet the element is appended to
   the DOM, but no icon.

   Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

**1st UPDATE:**

*sidebar.js*

Was modified to this:

```
...

var SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
        var XLink_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
        const use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'image');
        use.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '100');
        use.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100');
        use.setAttributeNS(XLink_NS, 'xlink:href', '../base/sprite.svg#icon-twitter' );

const twitterIcon = document.querySelector('.twitter__icon');
        twitterIcon.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", use);
```

***This produced a Webpack error***

```
ERROR in ./src/components/sidebar/sidebar.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'svg-sprite-loader' in '/Users/dev/Developer/projects/dcbio'
 @ ./src/components/sidebar/sidebar.js 10:0-28
 @ ./src/index.js
```

Commenting out `../sprite.svg` file took care of the said error. Yet, the browser now produces a 404 error that's driving me crazy.

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KQ7v.png)

**Elements Rendered**
[HLTM Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dWvh.png)

Recommendations is appreciated.

Thanks

**2nd UPDATE**

After reading through webpack's doc and its git, I made changes to my webpack.config to this:

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        index: 'index.html',
        port: 9000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader', 'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'

                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use:  [ 'file-loader'],

            },

            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [
                    {
                    loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                    options: {
                        extract: true,
                        publicPath: '/src'

                    }
                },
                    'svg-inline-loader',
                    'svgo-loader'
                ] 
            },

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [ '@babel/env' ],
                        plugins: [ 'transform-class-properties' ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.hbs$/,
                use: [
                    'handlebars-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.hbs',
            title: 'Hello world',
            description: 'Some description'

        }),
        new SpriteLoaderPlugin({
            plainSprite: true,
            spriteAttrs: {
                id: 'icon-twitter'
            }
        })
    ],
};
```

I still get a browser error - see pic

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWOgS.png)

DOM returns this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJOYj.png)

Comment: Just a guess here, but I see the file extension at the end of the href in your `<use>` element is `.sgv` instead of `.svg` (v and g are switched). Is that it?

Comment: Good catch, but nope.

Comment: I believe this will help you:  http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/javascript/

Comment: Please use [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS). You are using `document.createElement`. Also you'll need to use [use.setAttributeNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS) to set the `'xlink:href'` attribute. Also you'll need to put the `icon-twitter`in a "root svg" on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL Update and Answer:**

After extensive research and edits, I realized within my `base.js` file the property `inner.HTML` element contributed to the `<svg>` icon not loading.

In addition, I modified the following files mentioned on my original post to this:

**sidebar.js**

```
...

import symbol from '../../images/icons_sprite.svg';

...

html = `<svg class="icon-fb">
         <use href="#icons_sprite_icon-facebook"></use>
        </svg>`;

const iconBox = document.querySelector('.Icon-box');
iconBox.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
```

*Notice I'm only using `href` and NOT `xlink:href`. According to MDN documentation `xlink:href` is in the deprecation bucket, so I'm choosing to keep with their recommended approach - Just use `href`.*

**webpack.dev.config**

```
...
    {
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      include: /\.*_sprite\.svg/,
      use:[

       {
         loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
         options: {
             publicPath: './src',
         }
       },
       {
          loader: 'svgo-loader',
          options: {
          plugins: [
              { cleanupIDs: false },
          ]
       }
    },
..
```

Problem solved...

Here are the links that contributed to a resolution. I hope this solution provides help to someone in the future.
**MDN**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG 
**Webpack-svg**
https://github.com/JetBrains/svg-sprite-loader
https://github.com/svg/svgo
https://github.com/vp-online-courses/webpack-tutorial/compare/svg-sprites-begin...svg-sprites-end